# Simplify $(x^2-2x-x+2)(x-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $(x^2-2x-x+2)(x-3)$.

So here is my take on it (might me wrong correct me if I am wrong)

$$x^3-3x^2-2x^2+6x-x^2+3x+2x-6.$$

Now, what should I do?

Comment: Perhaps you can write $6x+3x+2x=11x$ and so on. Note that before you do anything you can simplify $x^2-2x-x+2$ to $x^2-3x+2$.

Comment: how you got 11x?

Comment: $6x+3x+2x=(6+3+2)x=11x$. Are you an elementary school student?

Comment: nvm 6x+ 3x + 2x = 11 x

Comment: @DougM It is $11x$ and not $5x$, do not cause more confusion.

Comment: sry i am just bad at math ....

Comment: Always combine like terms.

Comment: ok -3x^2 - 2x^2 = -5x^2

Comment: we have one more -x^2
so -5x^2 - x^2 = 4x^2 ??

Comment: oh yea i can make it x^2-3x+2

Comment: $-5x^2-x^2=(-5-1)x^2=-6x^2$ and not $4x^2$

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the idea is to use the fact that\begin{align}x^2-2x-x+2&=x(x-2)-(x-2)\\&=(x-1)(x-2).\end{align}And therefore your whole expression is equal to $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ (x-3)(x^{2} - 2x - x + 2) = (x-3)(x(x-2) - (x-2)) = (x-3)((x-2)(x-1)) = (x-3)(x-2)(x-1). $$
Notice that $-2x - x = -3x,$ yet it was not written as $-3x$ which should have sparked suspicion.